# Changing bit format on a Windows mobile device through direct draw APIs

Tags: windows, api, graphics, windows-mobile, gdi

I am working on a Windows Mobile 6.5 device and want to copy an image from one application (drawn using GDI) to another application (using direct draw). Currently I am doing bit conversion for this since the direct draw supports only 16-bit whereas the GDI image is written using 24-bit. I am wondering if we can change the direct draw format so that I can avoid this conversion.

```
DDPIXELFORMAT format;
m_pPrimarySurface->GetPixelFormat (&format);    
if (format.dwRGBBitCount == 16)
{
    format.dwRGBBitCount = 32;
    format.dwRBitMask  = 0x00FF0000;
    format.dwGBitMask  = 0x0000FF00;
    format.dwBBitMask  = 0x000000FF;
}
```

Is it possible to change the bit format by directly setting it or through any direct draw APIs like SetPixelFormat etc.? Or is this some hardware setting and cant be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API SetDisplayMode() says that "Windows CE does not support display mode changes".

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms893936.aspx